# Use MAX() on unicode data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column where the data type is char. But I want to change it to nchar to support unicode. So I alter the table and change the data type to nchar.

Table name: docheader

| id | docref |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TST/TT/22/02/0001 |
| 2 | TST/TT/22/02/0002 |
| 3 | TST/TT/22/02/0003 |
| 4 | TST/TT/22/02/0004 |

This is the query I use to get the max value of the column docref

```
SELECT MAX(docref) FROM docHeader WHERE docref LIKE 'TST/TT/22/02/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

By running this query, I am able to get the maximum value.

Result that I get:

| MAX(docref) |
| --- |
| TST/TT/22/02/0004 |

But, right after I change to nchar, I can't retrieve the max value of the column.

```
SELECT MAX(docref) FROM docHeader WHERE docref LIKE N'TST/TT/22/02/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

By running this query, it returns null to me.
Result that I get:

| MAX(docref) |
| --- |
| NULL |

My desired output is

| MAX(docref) |
| --- |
| TST/TT/22/02/0004 |

May I know why I can't use [0-9]? Is there any way to use this to search for the max value in nchar column?

Comment: and why do you change?

Comment: @nbk You mean change from char to nchar? As this column needs to support unicode.

Comment: are you sure you are using mysql?   mysql seems to support saying "nchar" as shorthand for utf8mb3, which does *not* support all of unicode.  highly recommend you use utf8mb4 instead.

Comment: to use a regular expression, use the REGEXP operator, not LIKE.

Comment: you may find it more helpful to test using `select count(*) from ...` instead of select max to see when you are getting any results at all

Comment: @ysth Yes, I do have the query to count(*), the reason of getting the max is to get the next value. Since it returns null, it will keep on generating the same number which cannot be saved as the docref should be unique

Comment: it returns null because your where finds no records

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: )

Comment: I suspected as much.  this is *not* mysql; mysql is an entirely different product, so most of what's been said is not applicable

Comment: It works just fine; please provide sample data that demonstrates your problem.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1da445bead02ecbd656173087501e3d1

Comment: @ysth I also not sure why when I run in my ssms, it returns null. But I got it, I use RTRIM() as explained in its documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

It mentioned

> When you use Unicode data (nchar or nvarchar data types) with LIKE, trailing blanks are significant; however, for non-Unicode data, trailing blanks aren't significant. Unicode LIKE is compatible with the ISO standard. ASCII LIKE is compatible with earlier versions of SQL Server.

If my data type is **nchar**, I need to use RTRIM() in order to get the max value.

```
SELECT MAX(docref) FROM docHeader WHERE RTRIM(docref) LIKE N'TST/TT/22/02/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

But if my data type is **nvarchar**, it works totally well when your query is as below. It works well also when RTRIM() is used.

```
SELECT MAX(docref) FROM docHeader WHERE docref LIKE N'TST/TT/22/02/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to regular r exprressiion like `REGEXP`'

> ```
> SELECT MAX(docref) FROM docHeader WHERE docref REGEXP  '^TST/TT/22/02/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
> ```
>
> ```
> MAX(docref)
> TST/TT/22/02/0004
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee2ea7c022cf04470f156842569b8fba)*